# Correct DHCP Server giving out incorrect Default Gateway

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, dns, dhcp

I have a very simple network setup that suddenly stopped working.

> SETUP

**HOST COMPUTER**
: Window 8

**Virtualization Software**: VirtualBox v5.1.22

**Virtual Machines**:

*Server*: Windows Server 2012 R2 (AD DS, DNS, DHCP service enable）

*Client*: Windows 10 Enterprise

*Virtual Network Configuration*: Both virtual machines are attached to `Internal Network` named SkyNet and should be on the same network.

> SERVER CONFIGURATION

Windows Server 2012 is the domain controller, and has a fixed IP address of 10.1.10.2 and subnet mask of 255.0.0.0.

Default gateway is manually set to 10.1.10.5, which is not really ping-able because there  is no router attached to this network.

Primary DNS server is 10.1.10.2, alternative DNS Server is 10.1.10.5.

DHCP server (10.1.10.2) has a scope of 10.1.10.100 to 10.1.10.200.

I have successfully added Win10 to the domain, and can obtain a correct IP address from the DHCP server every time I do `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew`.

However, instead of getting 10.1.10.5 as the default gateway, ipconfig on Win10 always returns 10.0.1.1 for default gateway.

`ipconfig /all` on Win10 will show correct domain name and DHCP Server.

I am able to ping WinServer 2012 from Win10, but not the other way around.
I cannot ping to the incorrect default gateway from with Win10.

I have no idea what might have caused this headache, as this is a completely(?) isolated network. There should not be a second DHCP server messing with it.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Check the IP Settings for the DHCP Client isn't overriding the Dynamic setting. Also, check what gateway the DHCP server is configured to give out (in Windows DHCP, it's under the scope options, as 003 Router). Also, if you are employing reservations, check that the router is not over written there, also.

Comment: Did you disable the DHCP service that VirtualBox can provide to the InternalNetwork ? If you did that in the past the upgrade to VBOX 5.1.22 may have enabled it again. This looks as if you have a 2nd DHCP server and Windows 10 combines the information which it is getting from both DHCP servers.

Comment: @Tonny thank you for the tip. I didnt VirtualBox does that. I will tey that when i get back to my computer.

Comment: @Hi, Steven. I looked into 003 Router. Turned out it was automatically set to 10.0.1.1. Thanks. After changing it back to 10.1.10.5, now I am able to get the correct DHCP server.  I still couldn't ping Win10 from WinServer 2012, even though Win10 firewall is turned off completely.